# How to load downloaded file into Media plugin using Cordova on Android?

Tags: android, cordova, media, file-transfer

Well I'm stumped.

Using cordova 6.1.1 I built a vanilla app and added the Media and File Transfer plugins. I then cribbed the code described in the [File Plugin CDVFile documentation](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file#cdvfile-protocol) to try to make the minimal javascript to download an MP3 from an external location and play it. So I replaced the default index.js with the following:

```
var onDeviceReady = function() {
  var fileURL = 'cdvfile://localhost/temporary/test.mp3'
  var uri = 'https://www.dropbox.com/s/1mg3pqfmkuc5g4p/Mad%20Dad%27s%20Song%20v2%20TRACK.mp3?dl=1'

  var onSuccessfulDownload = function (entry) {
    console.log("Successfully downloaded to: " + entry.toURL());

    var my_media = new Media(fileURL, function(){
      console.log("Successfully loaded");
      alert("Successfully loaded");
    }, function(err) {
      console.log("Failed to load" + JSON.stringify(err));
      alert("Failed to load" + JSON.stringify(err));
    });
    my_media.play();
  }


  var ft = new FileTransfer();
  ft.download(encodeURI(uri), fileURL, onSuccessfulDownload);
}

document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady, false);
```

When I run this on my Android devices (real, not emulated), the file successfully downloads ("`Successfully downloaded to: file:///data/data/com.example.media_test/cache/test.mp3`") but the Media object can't be created ("`Failed to load{"code":1}`"). Using `adb logcat` I can see that MediaPlayer tries to load the file but errors our not very verbosely:

```
V/MediaPlayer(15167): setListener
V/MediaPlayer-JNI(15167): setDataSourceFD: fd 151
V/MediaPlayer(15167): setDataSource(151, 0, 576460752303423487)
V/MediaPlayerService(  189): Create new client(106) from pid 15167, uid 10228, 
V/MediaPlayerService(  189): setDataSource fd=40, offset=0, length=576460752303423487
V/MediaPlayerService(  189): st_dev  = 45848
V/MediaPlayerService(  189): st_mode = 33152
V/MediaPlayerService(  189): st_uid  = 10228
V/MediaPlayerService(  189): st_gid  = 10228
V/MediaPlayerService(  189): st_size = 170536
V/MediaPlayerService(  189): calculated length = 170536
V/MediaPlayerService(  189): player type = 3
...snip ...
W/MediaExtractor(  189): FAILED to autodetect media content.
E/MediaPlayerService(  189):   error: -2147483648
... snip ...
E/MediaPlayer(15167): Unable to create media player
W/PluginManager(15167): THREAD WARNING: exec() call to Media.startPlayingAudio blocked the main thread for 33ms. Plugin should use CordovaInterface.getThreadPool().
... snip ...
I/chromium(15167): [INFO:CONSOLE(11)] "Failed to load{"code":1}", source: file:///android_asset/www/js/index.js (11)
```

- If I put the mp3 in with my source code I can play it by pointing Media at URL `/android_asset/www/test.mp3`, so I know it's not a problem with the file itself per se
- I can use the File plugin to CheckFile on the downloaded mp3 so I know it's there.
- I've tried adding `<access origin="cdvfile://*"/>` to config.xml and setting my Content-Security-Policy to `<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="* * 'self' default-src 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' http://* https://* data: cdvfile://* content://*;">`, to no avail.
- Changing the local path to `cdvfile://localhost/persistent/test.mp3` doesn't make a difference

Any hints on how I can debug this thing?

**EDIT:**

Also:

- Using external storage doesn't make a difference
- Passing the path to Media using `file://...` doesn't make a difference
- It's worth noting that if I pass a non-existent path to Media, that raises a different error. My problem isn't that Media can't find the file, it's that it can't open it after it's been downloaded. Even though it *can* open it when it's provided in `/android_asset/...`
- I can download an *image* to the same path and then display it onSuccessfulDownload with something like `document.getElementById('foo').src = fileURL;`. So the issue doesn't seem to be about reading and writing in general, but rather is specifically about opening that MP3 file.

Comment: What happens if you play it from the file url and not the cdvfile url (file:///data/data/com.example.media_test/cache/test.mp3)?

Comment: Thanks for asking - the exact same thing happens!

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know, you cant write files into application's cache directory until the device is rooted. So i doubt whether you are really able to view the file in the respective directory using any file explorer. 
 You can try using cordova.file.externalRootDirectory or cordova.file.externalRootDirectory instead. Also if you are testing it on Android Marshmallow, then you gotta use latest version of cordova file plugin (4.2.0) as old version seems to have permission issue with Marshmallow.Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but no joy, I'm afraid. Both externalRootDirectory and externalDataDirectory yield the same error, and it makes no difference whether I pass the 'file:///storage/emulated/0/...' style or the 'cdvfile://localhost/sdcard/' to the Media object. Incidentally, I believe an application can read/write its own cache directory - that's the point of having it after all - and that's all I'm trying to do. I'm not trying to view the file using an external file explorer.

Comment: @Patrick As i mentioned, have tried myself writing to application cache directory and it dint worked for me atleast using cordova file plugin.I understood from some analysis that we gotta have root access in device to get this done. i asked you to check whether the file is available in device using file explorer

Comment: Hi @Gandhi, writing to the application cache directory is working for me. E.g. I can download a PNG file to `cdvfile://localhost/temporary/test.png` and then display it in my app by setting an `img` `src` tag to that path once download completes. The file is _not_ available using a file explorer because the apps cache dir is private to the app, but that's sort of unrelated to the problem, because what I'm trying to achieve is all happening within one app.

Comment: @Patrick But in the post its mentioned that the file got downloaded to  "file:///data/data/com.example.media_test/cache/test.mp3"
If the download is successful, using file explorer you should be able to see the physical existence of the fail. Could you please try out scenario once in  a rooted device?

Comment: Aha! Ok, so what I've just discovered is that the issue isn't about where I'm downloading *to*, it's about where I'm downloading *from*. I checked the file I downloaded from dropbox, and it was only 166.5KB (the original is 2.7MB). So even though the FileTransfer plugin thought the download was succeeding, it was actually only managing a partial download. I don't know why - I can download the file just fine in a browser. When I changed the URL to point at an MP3 on a different host everything worked fine...